# Series of AsyncTask does not go for execution instantaneously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My MainActivity has 2 views: TextView and a Button. On button click, I am running an AsyncTask which further creates 10 new AsyncTasks for network operations. Every new task creation is delayed by 1 sec. The code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    TextView tv;
    Button t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);      
        t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                getData();
            }
        });
    }

    void getData()
    {
        SuperNetworkAsyncTask s = new SuperNetworkAsyncTask();
        s.execute("");
    }


    private class SuperNetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                {
                    nTask = new NetworkAsyncTask();
                    nTask.execute("");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }               
            return "";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {

        }                       
    }   


    private class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            tv.setText(result);
        }                       
    }

}
```

I was expecting that the moment first NetworkAsyncTask execute method is called, it will start execution. But when I run it, I do not find any NetworkAsyncTask begin its execution until the control comes out of SuperNetworkAsyncTask. Is there any way to push the execution of NetworkAsyncTask thread as soon as execute method is called?

Some clarifications:

Why NetworkAsyncTask are created by SuperNetworkAsyncTask? Because If I create the NetworkAsyncTask in main thread, I get my UI freeze for some time.

Why making 10 object? The purpose of NetworkAsyncTask is to read data from a server at interval of 1 sec for n seconds, here n=10.

**Part 2: Updates after doing some tests.**

Observation **1**:
As a fellow Brian shared a way to avoid creating AsyncTasks in nested way, I tried his code:

```
void getData() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                nTask = new NetworkAsyncTask();
                nTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

This freezes my UI for few seconds and then the screen is updated in a fraction of second. It is quite surprising to me too.

Observation **2**:

With java.lang.Thread, I experimented to make sure that 1) The threads should be executed right away when run() called. 2) The next task will be created only after previous task is finished.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myThread m;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        m=new myThread(String.valueOf(i));
        m.start();
        synchronized (m) 
        {
            try {
                m.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
}

public class myThread extends Thread
{

    public String name = "";

    public myThread(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {           
            System.out.println(" Thread Name = " + name);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            notifyAll();
        }   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread Name = 0
 Thread Name = 1
 Thread Name = 2
 Thread Name = 3
 Thread Name = 4
 Thread Name = 5
 Thread Name = 6
 Thread Name = 7
 Thread Name = 8
 Thread Name = 9
```

Based in this, I updated my NetworkAsyncTask & SuperNetworkAsyncTask as:

```
private class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {
            return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());              
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {
            tv.setText(result);
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

private class SuperNetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            nTask = new NetworkAsyncTask();
            nTask.execute(url);
            synchronized (nTask) 
            {
                try {
                    nTask.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }

        }               
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

    }                       
}
```

With this code the wait() keeps on waiting indefinitely.

Finally I replaced:

```
nTask.execute(url);
```

with

```
nTask.executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
```

This worked well as expected.

Comment: What's the sense of starting a series of AsyncTasks from another AsyncTask? You can do it from UI thread as well.

Comment: Use `executeOnExecutor` instead of `execute`. [From Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...)).

Comment: AsyncTask inside AsyncTask is not a good choice. Calling miultiple thread the order of execution parallel or serial depends on API version. `executeOnExecutor` can handle multiple thread running simultaneously.

Comment: what are you trying to do in those 10 `AsyncTask`s?

Comment: Why NetworkAsyncTask are created by SuperNetworkAsyncTask? Becasue If I create the NetworkAsyncTask in main thread, I get my UI freeze for some time.

Answer (score 0):

The UI will be updated only at `onPostExecute()`. See notes on AsyncTask
Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)! And Try to avoid 10 AysncTasks, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a "super async task" use a runnable and then create new async tasks in parallel

```
void getData() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                nTask = new NetworkAsyncTask();
                nTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Post honeycomb you can specify to run async tasks in parallel

Comment: Brian, Egor, pr38y: I just tried this code by Brian and also had tried this earlier. Everytime I get my screen freeze for, i guess 20 seconds. I know that this should not happen as one of my other app performs nicely when I create asynctasks from UI thread. I am surprised too. I am using 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` should be started in the UI thread, not on the one `doInBackground` runs on. You could call `publishProgress` after every sleep, and spawn each `AsyncTask` in the resulting calls to `onProgressUpdate`, which run on the UI thread.